# How to use COUNT, GROUP BY, and DATE_FORMAT in one Laravel 5 SQL Query?

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

I want to count the number of date appear in my table using Laravel 5 and SQL Query:

```
$tanggal = DB::table('entry')->count('*')->groupBy(DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%d-%m-%Y'));
```

But it can't work. Help me.

Comment: `it can't work`...can you be more specific? Are there errors in your logs? Do you see an error in your browser?

Comment: the error is "Call to a member function groupBy() on integer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `count()`, it is returning the number (as you saw in your error). Try swapping the functions and setting the `groupBy` parameter to be calculated raw:

```
$tanggal = DB::table('entry')
             ->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE(created_at)")
             ->count('*');
```

When you call `table()` it starts a query builder instance. A lot of query builder methods return the query builder again for method chaining, but some of them are final and return a result like `get()`, `first()`, and in this case `count()`.

I haven't tested the above code, but it should be close. You will also notice I changed it from `DATE_FORMAT` to just `DATE`. I can see you are trying to exclude the timestamp portion, and you can just use the latter instead of reformatting (which may slow down the query a tiny bit).

---

**EDIT:**

Ok, your question was not explained very well. From your comment, I think this is what you are looking for. Also, don't forget, Eloquent is a fantastic ORM, but it isn't a silver bullet and sometimes you may have to just raw plain SQL queries.

```
$results = DB::table('entry')
             ->addSelect(DB::raw('COUNT("*") as total)')
             ->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE(created_at)")
             ->get();
```

Comment: but i only get one result using this query, how to get all result?

Comment: If you want all of the results, `count()` is not what you want to do. That method counts the number of records that match and then returns the total count. If you want the records instead of the count, replace `->count('*')` with `->get()`

Comment: but i want to get all of the date and the number of its appearance